# Java Sum of multiples of 3 or 5 below N

Tags: java

Find the sum(integer) of all the multiples of **3 or 5** **below** N.
I have used the normal AP series formula for this calculation...but two of the test cases are coming wrong.Anyone can tell me whats wrong with this code? 
**I have not used loop that that shows termination due to timeout**

```
   int T = sc.nextInt();
   double f1 =0;
   double f2 =0;
   double f3 =0;
   double sum =0;
   for(int i =0; i<T; i++){
       int n = sc.nextInt();

  // n1,n2,n3 are the number of multiples 
   int n1 = (n-1)/3;   
   int n2 = (n-1)/5;   
   int n3 = (n-1)/15;

 // summation formula of AP series  
   f1 = (n1/2.0)*(6+(n1-1)*3);   
   f2 = (n2/2.0)*(10+(n2-1)*5);
   f3 = (n3/2.0)*(30+(n3-1)*15);

// summation multiples of 3 OR 5    
   sum = f1-f3+f2;

// Printing the final integer
   System.out.println((int)sum);
   }
}
```

}

Comment: What are the current results of this code?

Comment: for some test cases, its running fine...but for some others the output i incorrect.

Comment: Hi anamika, I don't understand why you do `int n1 = (n-1)/3;`. isn't the formula for AP : n/2(2a + (n-1)d)?

Comment: It says sum of multipes below N.For example..there are 3 multipes of 5 below 20...So, if n =20, (20-1)/5 gives me 3...which shows the number of multiples.I cannot include 20 as my multiple.In the AP series, n is the number of multiple.

Comment: ou I see, and with what inputs do you get the incorrect result?

Comment: The test cases are hidden...so i really cant see for what input its incorrect...Life would have been easier if i cud.Well, this one is from project euler,problem-1

Comment: erm, how'd you find out that it doesn't work for some cases?

Comment: I submitted my code nd 4/6 cases were correct...I must have made some mistake..i would be glad if you tell me how you would have solved this prob..just lemme kno of the algorithm to use..it will work..thanks :-)

Comment: The problem might be in the fact that double's wont always give exact results. However in this problem there is no need to work with doubles.  
You can just stick to integers, or maybe longs if integers are too small.  
Just rewrite your formulas for the sum so the division comes at the end. The outcome of such formulas should be an integer after all so then the division should be able to be made without having to round down as well.

Answer (score -2):

```
private int Sum(int N) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 3; i < N; i++) {
        if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0) {
            sum += i;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: downvoted because the code explains nothing. What is N? number of multiples? If yes, and I want sum of 2 multiples then your code wouldn't work.